# What is more effective to try to find ID or use JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join

I made this little function that finds user's ID and I have that ID available across website because I included it before `<head>`

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM korisnici WHERE username='".$_COOKIE["user"]."' AND password='".$_COOKIE["pass"]."'");
$get=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$ID_KORISNIK=$get["ID"];
if(empty($ID_KORISNIK))
{
    echo '
        <script>window.location="IDerror.php";</script>
        ';
}
```

So whan I want to SELECT or INSERT into database I could use

```
$r=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uzg WHERE IDkorisnik='$ID_KORISNIK'");
```

or use JOIN

```
$r=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uzg JOIN (uzg.IDkorisnik=korisnici.ID) WHERE korisnici.username='$_COOKIE["user"]' AND korisnici.password='$_COOKIE["pass"]'");
```

What do you think, which one is better or effective?

Comment: You could always try and run each option 1000+ times and see how long they take.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Don't** store password as a cookie
2. **Never** trust user input, your queries are subject to SQL injection attacks
3. **Don't** use `mysql_*` functions, use PDO or `mysqli_*`, and use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection attacks

I would recommend to learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi), and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

By the way I think your first solution is better (but you have to correct a lot of stuff)

Comment: I stored md5 of real password, that is ok? 

I'm using function that checks every entry and remove unwanted before I use mysql_query (http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/quoteSmart.htm).

mysqli? can I use that if I have mysql database

Comment: @FosAvance I edited my answer to add some info about mysqli and PDO. Btw mysqli is just a better driver for MySQL database.
Storing password as a cookie (even hashed) is not a good idea, use sessions to identify logged users

Comment: so username as cookie and password as session, if my user check Remember Me checkbox to stay logged in?

Answer (score 1):

if it is large project i would much like to use a User class
so i will simply call it by

$new_user->id;

but if not, your 1st approach is much better but you arent checking whether your input is a valid ID first,
once you confirm it is a valid ID [may be an existing int] then use your 1st approach

and storing your users PWD even as hash is BAD, since hashes are easily crackable
so if you want a verification against cookie stealing, put some other hash

Comment: some other hash?
why would user crack password on it's own computer.
What other should I store if not password to identify my user?

Comment: the problem is that cookie isnt a private property of the user, that where cookie stealing comes, someone can simply use a JS code to grab the cookie and crack the hash, now he has both the user ID along with the pwd..  to completly prevent such would involve https, but a good fix would be to store the IP/USer agent/ of the user to authenciate him